# Assigning php variable to javascript alerts PHP source code

Tags: javascript, php

I want to assign the php variable `$stop` to the javascript variable `stopped`

```
<?php
    $stop = $_POST['stop'];
?>
<script>
    var stopped = "<?php echo($stop) ?>";
    alert(stopped); //Output: alertbox with the text: <?php echo($stop) ?>
</script>
```

How can I solve this?

Comment: **Danger**: This code is [vulnerable to XSS](https://www.owasp.org/index.php/Cross-site_Scripting_(XSS)). User input needs escaping before being inserted into an HTML document or JavaScript!.

Comment: Is your page parsed by the PHP interpreter?

Comment: Your file is `.php`? And guys, why are you downvoting this question? It seems so clear for me.

Comment: @Quentin, I have protect it against XSS, but I want to make it simple to explain, and @ j08691 no the only thing that is alerted is the plaintext: <?php echo($stop) ?>.

Comment: Works for me. Double check everything that's being recommended.

Comment: @user3009553 — If you have implemented protection from XSS, then you removed that protection when creating your test case (or it is a blacklist filter instead of (the much, much safer) escaping approach). The code you have there is vulnerable.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the PHP source code is being alerted, the document is not being run through the PHP preprocessor before being delivered to the browser.

Make sure that:

- You're using a web server and not loading from a local file
- The webserver supports PHP
- The file the PHP code is in is one the server expects to find PHP in (typically this will be a file with a `.php` extension, but it is configurable).

Comment: Yes all that stuffs work, My totally site (a catalogus site), is working perfectly (it is php)

Comment: Then something is wrong with the way this specific file is being handled, because PHP is not parsing the php code in it. Put `<?php phpinfo(); ?>` at the top of the file and reload it in your browser; do you see the phpinfo page? If not, then maybe an .htaccess file is preventing this file from being parsed?